# Show dropdown selected value in the grid on the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, asprepeater

I have a drop down which has the list of delegates. When the user selects a delegate then I populate the available meet-timings in the second dropdown using the selectedindexchange event of the 1st dropdown
Aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="delegate_ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddldelegates_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="200px"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="delegatetime_ddl" runat="server" Width="90px"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="adddelegate" runat="server" Text="Add" onclick="adddelegate_Click"/>
```

.cs page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataSet ds1 = getdata.getdelegatelist();
                delegate_ddl.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
                delegate_ddl.DataTextField = "DELEGATE_NAME";
                delegate_ddl.DataValueField = "DELEGATE_ID";
                delegate_ddl.DataBind();
                delegate_ddl.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--"); 
            }

        }
        protected void ddldelegates_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string delselection = delegate_ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();
            DataSet ds2 = getdata.getdelegatetimelist(delselection);
            if (ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                delegatetime_ddl.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];
                delegatetime_ddl.DataTextField = "TIMESLOT";
                delegatetime_ddl.DataValueField = "TIMEID";
                delegatetime_ddl.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                time_lbl.Text = "No slots Open";
            }
        }
        protected void adddelegate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string delegateselected = delegate_ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string timeslotselected = delegatetime_ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();
            getdata.delegatemeetinsert(personidd, delegateselected, timeslotselected);
        }
```

Now the data gets inserted – but my question here is
As soon as the user click add button I would like to display the delegate  selected and the time slot selected in a some sort of a grid view or dynamic table below with a delete option.
Can someone please provide a code sample in C# to achieve the above

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Gridview for displaying data use some basic control like Labels,it will reduce lot's of unncessary code. use Asp.net 'Panel' control and encapsulate all label and button(for delete purpose) into Panel then hide/show according to need. here is the outline of code that might help you,

```
if(!page.IsPostBack) // This goes into Page_Load
{
Panel1.Visible=false;
}

protected void adddelegate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   // add this additional code
{
Panel.Visible=True;
GetDelegate()// This method retrieve the delegate you inserted..
Lable1.Text= "Set here Delegate name you just Retrieved"
Label2.Text="Delegate time you retrived"
}

protected void BtnRemovedelegate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
string Personidd= retrieve person id
string delegateName= Lable1.text;
String timeslot=Label2.Text
SomeDeleteMethod(personidd, delegateName, timeslot); 
Panel1.Visible=false;
}
```

Hope you get the idea..

Comment: Hi i really like this idea. but how do i add multiple rows. user can select multiple delegates.the sample you showed will be good for one row but how do i add for multiple rows - could you show some sample code

Comment: I thought you just wanted to show newly inserted record only..but if you want to show multiple records you can use grid. you just need to replace Labels and buttons in panel's with Grid.